# Error opening second ttyUSB port

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I'm programming a Linux embedded computer.

Linux version: Linux 2.6.28

This linux device has only one USB port and I need two ports. So I have added a USB hub (Deltaco HU-480). When I connect two usb devices (RS232- adatpter with profilink PL2303 chips) I can see that they are found in /dev and they are named ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1.

When I try to open these two port in my c++ program I get an error opening the second port.

This is my code:

```
int USB0 = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NDELAY );
perror("USB0 ");
sleep (5);

int USB1 = open( "/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NDELAY );
perror("USB1 ");
sleep(5);
```

And this is the result:

USB0 : Success

USB1 : Protocol error

It dosent matter if i open ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 first, it is alyways the second port that fails to open. If I close the first port before opening the second port it opens correctly.

Any idea why it is not possible to have the two ports open at the same time?

Comment: You should not check `errno` (which is what `perror` does) unless there actually is an error. I.e. only call `perror` if the previous system call failed. You can check if `open` fails by checking the return value, if it's `-1` then there was a failure and you can use `perror`.

Comment: The problem seem to be RS232 adapter specific. The RS232 adapter is a Trendnet TU-S9.
When connecting two OBD readers with same chipset (PL2303) it works fine to open two ttyUSB ports.

Comment: When I compare the info from "lsusb -v" the only thing that differs is the "bcdDevice" TU-S9 has bcdDevice=4.00 and OBD reader has bcdDevice=3.0.

Comment: My problem seem to be the same as described in this post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=7900&p=465123&hilit=Multiple+USB+%3E+Serial+adaptors#p465123

Comment: Any solution to this? I have the same issue with my two devices plugged into USB on my rpi. I am using c++.